# adding legend to ggmap with geom_point positions from different datasets

Tags: r, legend, ggmap

I've been plotting two sets of positional data with geom_point from different data sets (MR + MRTag).

```
MR
detect_date        Latitude      Longitude    species
12/04/2016 11:08    -6.6524      71.3475      Manta Ray
12/04/2016 11:09    -6.6524      71.3475      Manta Ray
12/04/2016 11:10    -6.6524      71.3475      Manta Ray
16/04/2016 21:27    -6.6524      71.3475      Manta Ray

MRTag
species    taggingdate   deploy_lat  deploy_lon
Manta Ray   3/24/2016   -5.4191      71.83855
Manta Ray   02/05/2013  -5.2568      71.65768333
Manta Ray   02/07/2013  -5.33448     71.9812
Manta Ray   02/08/2013  -5.3046      71.94231667
```

I then used the code below to  make a base map

```
library(ggmap)

MR_bbox <- make_bbox(lon = MR$Longitude, lat = MR$Latitude, f=1)
MR_map <- get_map(location = MR_bbox, source = "google", maptype = "satellite")
```

Then plotted my location data from Mr + MRTag onto the map

```
  MR_plot <-
    ggmap(MR_map) + 
     geom_point(data = MR, mapping = aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), 
        shape = 1, color = "white") +
     geom_point(data = MRTag, mapping = aes(x = deploy_lon, y = deploy_lat),
       shape = 25, fill = "#00FF00", color = "#00FF00") +
     xlab("Longitude") + 
     ylab("Latitude")
```

This gave me this plot

[image]

I'd like to add a legend for the two shapes to the map but I'm not sure of the best way to do it, and methods so far haven't worked

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a reproducible example. This will give people who want to help you something to work with and to test. 
You can read about it **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually really simple: just move the relevant aesthetic arguments into the `aes()`.

```
MR_plot <- ggmap(MR_map) + 
    geom_point(data = MR, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude,
                              color = 'detect', shape = 'detect', fill = 'detect')) +
    geom_point(data = MRTag, aes(x = deploy_lon, y = deploy_lat,
                                 color = 'tag', shape = 'tag', fill = 'tag')) +
    xlab("Longitude") + 
    ylab("Latitude") +
    scale_color_manual(name = 'legend', values = c(detect = 'white', tag = '#00FF00')) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = 'legend', values = c(detect = NA, tag = '#00FF00')) +
    scale_shape_manual(name = 'legend', values = c(detect = 1, tag = 25))
```

It's actually slightly confusing: if you use `color=` outside the `aes()`, then you set the actual color of those points and there is no legend because it's purely an aesthetic choice.

If you use `color=` (or `fill=` or `shape=`) inside the `aes()`, however, what you're doing is defining another variable that controls the color of the points. If you wanted to color those points based on species, for example, your `aes()` would be: `aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = species)`. This is same thing: except by passing a single string you set the color variable for all points in that `geom_point` to a single value.

You then have to use a `scale_color_*` function (and corresponding functions for fill and shape) to set those color variables to the specific colors you want. By default, each scale defined in the `aes()` will get it's own legend. But if you name the legends and give them the same name, then they will be combined into one.